# How can I distort a buffered image

Tags: java, bufferedimage

Distortion example
[image: Distortion example]

I am trying to make a 3D game from scratch, and I have working code that draws 3D cubes to the screen using `Graphics.drawPolygon(int[] {0,0,0}, int[] {0,0,0}, 3);` using 2 per side of the cube. I am trying to make a "mask" with images, but in order to do this, I need to be able to distort my images. Is there any way of doing this? I haven't been able to find any resources on this topic online.

Comment: Read this [tutorial about transforming](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html).

Comment: Apply a [transformation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html). --- http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: The shear transformation worked perfectly for what I'm needing! Thank you for the advice and pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

This is called an 'affine transform': a transform that preserves parallel lines. See [`java.awt.geom.AffineTransform`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html).